# How to Delete Data React Native SQLite

Tags: sqlite, react-native, expo

I'm facing some problem and I'm still new with this react native and SQLite thing but how do I delete a data from database if the create method is like this?

```
simpanCatatan = async () => {
        const { navigation } = this.props
        const date = new Date()
        const dateNow = date.getDate() + " " + bulan[date.getMonth()] + " " + date.getFullYear()
        await Catatan.create({
          title: this.state.title,
          value: this.state.catatan,
          user_id: this.state.user_id,
          video_id: this.state.idVideo,
          video_name: this.state.namaVideo,
          materi_id: this.state.idMateri,
          created_at:dateNow
        })
        navigation.goBack()
        navigation.state.params.getAllCatatan()        
    }
```